# Zend_Mail and Mailtrap : bad sender address

Tags: php, smtp, zend-mail, mailtrap

I'm sending email to mailtrap in this way

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom("senderaddress@yahoo.it", 'Temporary sender name');
```

I am already using mail trap for a lot of projects, so I know that I can send email using these email address and name as "from"

### What doesn't works

The problem is that `$mail->send()` throws an Exception

```
5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax
```

### Little debug

So I debugged Zend code. I am now sure it's sending from as

```
Temporary sender name <senderaddress@yahoo.it>
```

I also tried avoiding litteral name, so using only

```
 $mail->setFrom("senderaddress@yahoo.it");
```

The header is written using only

```
 <senderaddress@yahoo.it>
```

But nothing changed

### What I'm not understanding

I am not able to understand if this *very* old Zend project is NOT sending at all the message or if Mailtrap is refusing.

### Questions

- What is wrong with this sender address ?
- Is this an error from Zend_Mail or from Mailtrap?
- And obviously, how to fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
Zend_Mail::setDefaultFrom('senderaddress@yahoo.it', 'Temporary sender name');
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('...Your message here...');
$mail->send($transport);
```